# P-table Horizontal Scroll Not Displaying

Tags: html, scroll, primeng

I have the following attributes in my p-table:

```
<p-table
   [columns]="this.templateRows"
   [value]="this.tableData"
   [scrollable]="true"
   scrollHeight="100px"
   scrollWidth="100px"
   scrollDirection="both"
>
```

However, the horizontal scroll isn't working, which means my columns are all bunched up with text overlapping. The vertical one is working fine.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by changing to this:

```
  <p-table
    [columns]="this.templateRows"
    [value]="this.tableData"
    [resizableColumns]="true"
    [autoLayout]="true"
  >
```